# Equivalent curves

Tags: vector-analysis

Giving 2 intervals $I,J\in\mathbb{R}$ and 2 continuous functions $u: I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ and $v: J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, we say that $u$ and $v$ are equivalent and we write $u\approx v$ if there exists an increasing function (possibly not strictly increasing) $\phi : I\rightarrow J$ such that $\phi(I)=J$, and for every discontinuity point $x\in I$ of $\phi$, the interval $[\phi_{-}(x),\phi_{+}(x)]$ is contained in an interval $[\tau_1,\tau_2]\subset J$ on which $v(y)=c(\tau_1,\tau_2)\in\mathbb{R}^d$ for all $y\in [\tau_1,\tau_2]$, and $u(x)=v(\phi(x))$ for all $x\in I$.

Prove that $\approx$ is an equavalent relation. Can any one help me with this problem ?

Comment: If you've done the reflexive part (or more), can you show us?

Comment: I got stuck from the reflexive part

Comment: Sorry, I did the reflexive part. We just choose $\phi$ is the identity function from I to I. I got stuck on the symmetry and transitive .

Comment: Can any one help me with the symmetry and transitive part ?

Comment: Wouldn't symmetric just be taking the inverse and transitive be taking composition? Then it suffice to check they satisfy the properties.

Comment: The problem is that $\phi$ is not strictly increasing, So we can not take the inverse function

Comment: Can any one give me an answer ?